# Accessing NSMutableArray Difficulties

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to build an NSMutableArray each time a button is pressed.  I am using NSLog to check the array count after each button pressed and the value is zero.  THe code is below.

ProjectViewController.h

```
NSMutableArray *numberQuery
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *numberQuery;
```

ProjectViewController.m

```
- (void)makeButtons{
UIButton * pickButton;
int y_plot = 150;
int x_plot = 70;
int z = 0;

for(int y = 1; y < 10; y++)
{

    for(int x = 1; x < 5; x++){
        z++;

        pickButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        pickButton.frame = CGRectMake(x*x_plot, y_plot, 60, 40);

        [pickButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnUnselected.png"]     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [pickButton addTarget:self action:@selector(digitClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [pickButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",z] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        pickButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
        pickButton.tag = z;
        [self.view addSubview:aButton];
    }
    y_plot=y_plot+45;
  }
}

//************************
- (void)digitClick:(id)sender{
UIButton * chosenButton =(UIButton *)sender;

if ([sender isSelected] ==FALSE) {  
    [sender setSelected:TRUE];
    [chosenButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnSelected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    chosenButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    if([queryNumbersX count]<6){
        [self numberSearchArray:chosenButton.tag];
        }
    }
else
    {[sender setSelected:FALSE];
    [chosenButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnUnselected.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    chosenButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}

forState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSLog(@"clicked button with title %d",chosenButton.tag); 
}

//************************
-(void) numberSearchArray:(NSInteger)newNumber;
{

   [self.numberQuery addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: newNumber]];
   NSLog(@"numberSearchArray %d - count %d",newNumber, [self.numberQuery count]);  
}
```

Am I using the NSMutableArray in the right manner...declaration?

This is the code in the viewDidLoad method

```
NSMutableArray *numberQuery = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
```

Although I have the array declared int he header file,  It seems as though I cannot access it outside of the method in which it was allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *numberQuery;
```

You must balance that with

```
@synthesize numberQuery;
```

in the .m

and the correct creation would be

```
self.numberQuery = [NSMuatableArray arrayWithCapacity:someNumber];
```

---

By doing this

```
NSMutableArray *numberQuery = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
```

You are not using your @property you are creating a new variable, this is why you get the warning that your variable is not use, because it's scope is actually just the `viewDidLoad` method instead of the object.

Comment: you can also use a convenient method `self.numberQuery = [NSMutableArray array];`. This array is autoreleased, so your retaining property is balanced. Also using the `initWithObjects:` and just passing nil look suspicious.

Comment: @vikingosegundo you are right I will modify it for `+ (id)arrayWithCapacity:(NSUInteger)numItems` that would be better

Comment: THanks, VinceBurn!  Worked perfectly now!

Comment: The best about convenient factory methods: you don't have to worry, if ARC is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you have never alloced `numberQuery`. So it is always nil and thus `addObject` method is ignored. You need to alloc this in `init` (or any suitable place you like) and release in `dealloc` (or in other suitable place).

Comment: I actually allocate it in the viewDIdLoad method.  I get a warning message stating that the variable is never used.

Comment: I hav added the allocation statement to the original question.